# Добавить select multiple в профиль пользователя WP

Tags: wordpress

Нужно добавить список множественного выбора в профиль пользователя:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал код:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields' );
function show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
  <?php global $wpdb;
  $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM {$wpdb->prefix}cafe", OBJECT );
  ?>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="cafe">Label name</label></th>
            <td>
                <select name="cafe[]" id="cafe" multiple="multiple">
                    <?php foreach ($results as $cafe) { ?>
                        <option value="cafe_<?php echo $cafe->id; ?>" <?php selected('cafe_'.$cafe->id, get_the_author_meta( 'cafe', $user->ID )['0'] ); ?>><?php echo $cafe->name; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM {$wpdb->prefix}cafe", OBJECT );

    foreach ($results as $cafe) {
        $cafe_name = "cafe_".$cafe->id;
        if ( isset( $_POST[$cafe_name] ) ){
            update_user_meta( $user_id, $cafe_name, $_POST[$cafe_name] );
        }else{
            update_user_meta( $user_id, $cafe_name, 'off' );
        }
    }

}
```

Проблема видимо в ф-и сохранения, но как сделать правильно я хз.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields' );
function show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
  <?php global $wpdb;
  $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM {$wpdb->prefix}cafe", OBJECT );
  $current_selections = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'cafe', true );
  ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="cafe">Label name</label></th>
            <td>
                <select name="cafe[]" id="cafe" multiple="multiple" style="min-width: 250px;">
                    <?php foreach ($results as $cafe) { ?>
                        <option value="cafe_<?php echo $cafe->id; ?>" <?php echo ( !empty( $current_selections ) && in_array( 'cafe_'.$cafe->id, $current_selections ) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ) ?>><?php echo $cafe->name; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<?php }
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['cafe'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'cafe', $_POST['cafe'] );
    }
}
```